# Chinese Characters are displayed as junk characters in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have sent Chinese text to the other page as a querystring. Before that i have stored the text in the variable. When i check the text in the debug mode it displayed as junk characters.
I have used the following in the ASPX page,

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
```

But still it is displayed junk characters.

Is there anything i need to change to display the valid unicode text?

Comment: Define "junk characters", do you mean the placeholder glyph of the font (probably a centre dot or box), or corrupted?

Comment: How about showing us the problem code?  That said: is the font you're using capable of displaying Chinese characters? Are you using appropriate encodings where you need to?

Comment: Its shows squares for every character

Answer (score 0):

Your meta tag is malformed. It should be:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
```

`charset` is not an attribute on its own, but part of the `content` attribute.

See [w3](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset).